# Illegal monitor state exception java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class user which writes json objects to a file

```
public class User {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, org.json.simple.parser.ParseException{
        writetofile();
        Q q= new Q();
        Writer write = new Writer("write",q);
//      System.out.println(q.queue.poll());
        Reader reader = new Reader("read",q);
    }
    public static void writetofile() throws IOException{
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("file1.txt");
        for(int i=0;i<3;++i){
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("Name", rand_s());
            obj.put("Age", rand_i());
            file.write(obj.toJSONString());
            file.flush();
            file.write("\r\n");
    //      System.out.println("Successfully Copied JSON Object to File...");
        //  System.out.println("\nJSON Object: " + obj);
        }
    }
    public static String rand_s(){
        final String AB = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( 12 );
           for( int i = 0; i < 12; i++ ) 
              sb.append( AB.charAt( rnd.nextInt(AB.length()) ) );
           return sb.toString();
    }
    public static String rand_i(){
        final String AB = "0123456789";
        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( 2 );
           for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) 
              sb.append( AB.charAt( rnd.nextInt(AB.length()) ) );
           return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

I have a class writer which writes the Json documents from file to a queue and a class reader which reads from queue and prints the objects and deletes them from queue

Below is writer class

```
package org.mmt;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class Writer implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    Q q;
    Writer(String name,Q q){
        t= new Thread(this,name);
        this.q = q;
        t.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        String FileName="file1.txt";
        try {
            ArrayList<JSONObject> jsons=ReadJSON(new File(FileName),"UTF-8");
            for(JSONObject ob1 : jsons){
                q.put(ob1);
                notifyAll();
//              System.out.println(q.queue.poll());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static synchronized ArrayList<JSONObject> ReadJSON(File MyFile,String Encoding) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException, org.json.simple.parser.ParseException {
        Scanner scn=new Scanner(MyFile,Encoding);
        ArrayList<JSONObject> json=new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    //Reading and Parsing Strings to Json
        while(scn.hasNext()){
            JSONObject obj= (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(scn.nextLine());
            json.add(obj);
        }
        return json;
    }

}
```

Below is reader class

```
package org.mmt;

import java.util.Queue;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Reader implements Runnable {

    Thread t;
    Q q;
    Reader(String name,Q q){
        t=new Thread(this,name);
        this.q=q;
        t.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(!q.empty()){
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj = q.get();
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
        while(q.empty()){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and below is the Q class which contains the queue in which  data has to be written

```
package org.mmt;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;


public class Q {
    public Queue<JSONObject> queue = new LinkedList<JSONObject>();
    public synchronized JSONObject get(){
        return queue.poll();
    }
    public synchronized void put(JSONObject obj){
        try{
        queue.add(obj);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public boolean empty(){
        return queue.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

I have started threads in reader and writer for simultaneous reading and writing  and whenever queue is empty reader class waits() and whenever writer writes an element to queue  I use notifyall() for reader to resume but I am getting Illegal monitor state exception. I have searched the internet and found that this occurs whenever thread tries to take lock of monitor which it does not own but I am not able to resolve the issue

Comment: It would be much easier (and tidier) to use a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your `Reader` and `Writer` classes need to **share** the monitor object. In your example `Reader` is using itself as a monitor, and `Writer` is using itself as a monitor.

In your case you could use the `Queue q` itself as a monitor because that is your state that needs synchonization.
Also the callers need to own the monitor, they usually take ownership like this:
`syncronized (q)  { //do stuff on q}`
In other words, wait/notify should be called only in  a synchronized block, which is synchronized on the object.

[More about wait/notify here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify())

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that exception because you **aren't in a monitor**.

```
public class User {
    public static final Object lock = new Object();

    ...

    synchronized(User.lock) {
        while(q.empty()){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

public class Writer implements Runnable {
    ...
        for(JSONObject ob1 : jsons){
            q.put(ob1);
            synchronized(User.lock) {
                notifyAll();
            }
     //     System.out.println(q.queue.poll());
        }
```

Please note I haven't worked with `synchronized` and concurrency like this in a while, so I'm not sure if this is entirely thread-safe or not.

Mostly because if you end up with

```
synchronized(lock) {
    synchronized(Q) {
```

and

```
synchronized(Q) {
    synchronized(lock) {
```

Then you'll get a deadlock at some point, and your app will freeze. That's why I'm personally wary of `synchronized` methods.